# AngularDart: What is the meaning "static _nop(e) => e;"

Tags: angularjs, filter, dart, angular-dart

What is the meaning of function name "_nop(e)"?
What does it do?

I could not find reference anywhere regarding this function.
(I not asking about function Dart syntax, I am understand the function shorthand here)
(I am not sure, but I presume it means no operation on expression element "e".)

"static _nop(e) => e;"

reference:
line 139 of order_by.dart (see link below)

https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/lib/formatter/order_by.dart

Comment: I'm not into Dart, but this function just returns first argument. Further in code it's used as empty mapper that does nothing with value.

Comment: Thanks Everyone! It confirms my understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a default for something where a custom implementation can be passed in. The default implementation does nothing special - just return the argument. A custom implementation probably pass another method that has some more functionality. I guess `_nop` means `No Operation`.

Comment: Thanks Everyone! It confirms my understanding

Answer (score 0):

As Klaster already said: the `=>` syntax is the same as "return".

Thus `static _nop(e) => e` is the same as `static _nop(e) { return e; }`.

In general nop means no operation. I can't tell you why they need that but the function just returns the value.

Gerards,
Robert

Comment: Thanks Everyone! It confirms my understanding. BR